# How can I use Python to take a screenshot of a webpage given its URL?

Tags: python

Is there a method to capture a screenshot of a website's main page using the CLI?

I know that Selenium offers this capability, but my code runs on a GUI-less Linux server.

I tried to use url2png API as an alternative but I want to implement native code.

Comment: You may be able to use Selenium with Chrome in headless mode. I'm not sure if Chrome still needs a display when it's in headless mode. Generally, you need an engine capable of parsing and rendering HTML, CSS, and (optionally) Javascript. The best way to get that capability is to use a browser. Note that URL2PNG very likely does it this way in the background.

Comment: Do I need to install Chrome as well?

Comment: Yes, Chrome would need to be installed. Chromium might be an alternative though I don't know if it works with Selenium.